# I want to print the "\" character in python but I get "\\"

Tags: python, unicode, character

I have a python list of strings with `000_S_0000` formatting. Since I want this list to be displayed in a LaTeX document, I want to save it first in a .txt file using a different formatting for each of its strings, specifically this one: `000\_S\_0000`.

However, when I wrote the modified list in the .txt file, each string was formated as `000\\_S\\_0000` instead.

How could I solve that? Why isn't it working?

Thanks in advance!

This is my code:

```
def posa_barres_latex(ll_PTIDs):
    for i in range(len(ll_PTIDs)):
        snou = ''
        for caracter in ll_PTIDs[i]:
            if caracter == "_":
                snou = snou + "\_"
            else:
                snou = snou + caracter
        ll_PTIDs[i] = snou
    with open("sortida_exclosos_criteri_c.txt","w") as f:
        f.write(str(ll_PTIDs))


posa_barres_latex(['002_S_2043', '018_S_2138', '013_S_2324', '129_S_4073', '002_S_4237', '019_S_4285', '130_S_4468', '136_S_4517', '013_S_4791', '031_S_4194','002_S_4219', '002_S_4251', '136_S_4408', '130_S_4605', '130_S_4925', '013_S_4985'])
```

P.S. I am using python 3.

Comment: `print("000\\_S\\_000")` and `print("000\_S\_000")` both print `000\_S\_000` in my python 3.6

Comment: It's hard to understand the details of your problem without a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: _"When I try to print the character \..."_ - how exactly are you trying to print it? Show the code which does that.

Comment: @Prune, thanks for the advice. I have modified it to meet these requirements, I hope :)

Comment: @americansanti -- *much* better; thanks.  I've retracted my closure vote and reversed the down-vote.  I also see that you have two worthy answers.

Answer (score 1):

To print a single '\' using the print command just use:
`print('\\')`

The first '\' *escapes* the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python version matters in this case.

But '\' is the escape character, it's used to encode other characters, for example '\n' is a newline.

You can escape '\' as `\\` and it'll just print '\'.

If you're using strings with a lot of them, it might be easier to use raw strings - just put an r in front of them. Example:

`print(r"000\_S\_000")`

Will print it exactly as you type it.

Comment: Thanks, it works for printing only one character, but for recursively doing it does not. If I want to save it in a .txt file I can't either.

Comment: What do you get now when you try this? Are you using raw strings or escaping with `\\\` ?

Comment: When I use the code I provided, I get this: `['002\\_S\\_2043', '018\\_S\\_2138', '013\\_S\\_2324', '129\\_S\\_4073', '002\\_S\\_4237', '019\\_S\\_4285', '130\\_S\\_4468', '136\\_S\\_4517', '013\\_S\\_4791', '031\\_S\\_4194', '002\\_S\\_4219', '002\\_S\\_4251', '136\\_S\\_4408', '130\\_S\\_4605', '130\\_S\\_4925', '013\\_S\\_4985']`

Comment: This seems to be the repr of a list. Try printing each item of the list instead, it'll probably look normal.

Comment: Also you don't need to iterate over the whole list and rewrite it each time, try using str.replace('_', r'\\_') instead.